# Excel formula for extracting numeric input

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that contains a number starting `2007***`. Counting down it changes.

I was wondering if there is a formula to take out the number and show it in as a separate column.

```
   Cell                         Extracted number
1: BlaBlaBla 200759 Blablabla | 200759
2: BlaBlaBla 200734 Blablabla | 200734
```

For now I only get something with `=search` but it's a strange number.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: **Saw your post** - what post?

Answer (score 0):

If the number is always surrounded by space it will work:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```